# Entity Manager find after merge

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, jta

We are facing a bug that is not always happening in our app, it happens when we use Entity manager find after updating an entity, for some reason it is retrieving the outdated version of the entity.

Is this happening because of the transaction taking time to commit the changes? and why is it not always happening?

The code for fetching the entity and updating it based on the primary key:

```
Order order = em.find(order.class, orderId);
em.refresh(order);
order.setStatus("OPEN");
em.merge(order);
em.flush();
```

The code after updating in another method (same order id):

```
Order order = em.find(order.class, orderId);
if (order == null) return;

if (!"OPEN".equals(order.getStatus))
    throw new Exception(...);
else 
   //some logic
```

Sometimes, the exception is thrown, meaning the order status is not changed yet.

We are using JTA with weblogic and eclipse persistence as the JPA implementation.

If anyone has any clue what might be causing this, I would be grateful, if any extra info is required, feel free to call it out.

Comment: In order to understand the context it is helpful to provide full method code. for example the code is inside a method annotated with @Transactional

Answer (score 2):

Is the two methods in the same transaction ? if not, it's possible that the the first transaction is not committed when you call the second method.
Second thing to  verify, is the cache, it's possible that you implement the second level of cache by default, it cause error like this.

Comment: Methods are in different APIs that are being called directly after each other IF the first one (the update) was successful, and as I mentioned before, it is not always happening

Comment: Is it successful or committed ? because flush()  doesn't and the transaction.
You have to make sur that the first transaction end before calling the second method.

Comment: The update method is a centralized method that is working for all our APIs without using getTransaction().commit() (only flush), I think this is not the issue, if it was why is not always happening? and if so, why aren't our other APIs crashing as well

Comment: Even if the transaction wasn't ended, this doesn't mean that the changes were not reflected in the database, I am really leaning towards the caching, problem is the bug is happening randomly and I can't reproduce it without releasing it to production.

Comment: I have to add that we are using a container-managed transaction, which basically means we don't need to explicitly start/end the transaction.

Comment: In this case, you can activate the transaction Log in Spring, and compare between the time of commit and the time of the second method call.

log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG

Comment: Can I use it with EclipseLink?

Comment: I think yes, you can find in this page the different levels of EclipseLink logging.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging